# Create views with CRUD Doctrine inside a custom Bundle

Tags: doctrine, crud, symfony

when i launch this command

```
php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud --entity=CustomBundle:Test
```

Doctrine create relative views inside

```
symfony/app/resource/views/test
```

but my CustomBundle with relative entities are created inside

```
symfony/app/src/CustomBundle/Entity
```

So, the problem is: how to create these views inside

```
symfony/app/src/CustomBundle/views
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that command don't have any options for that. You can see all the available options in the  [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html). But if you really need that then you must override the SensioGeneratorBundle, you can see how to extend any bundle in [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html). Then override the php class vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Generator/DoctrineCrudGenerator.php, then find the action 
"generate" and locate this line:

```
$dir = sprintf('%s/Resources/views/%s', $this->rootDir, str_replace('\\', '/', strtolower($this->entity)));
```

replace with:

```
$dir = sprintf('%s/Resources/views', $this->rootDir);
```

I have not tried it but  in theory that should work. Since you have the intention to create all the views in there then maybe you need to override the name for each generated view, you can see an action for each one below in that class.

Hope this help you.

Comment: doesn't work: new views now are located 

symfony/app/resource/views/test

Comment: this is so strange: when i've created a bundle all work fine. Controllers and entities are stored in the right dir. Views not...

Comment: the problem is that the controller for each entity has a different name, but all the show views all named , show.html.twig, so, need to be in different folders for each entity

Comment: It, seems that this behavior was changed in 3.x and by default views are stored in general Resources/views. Could you try $dir = sprintf('%s/Resources/views', $this->bundle->getPath());

Comment: This is work... BUT... no directory was created. Now i can see the four views inside MyBundle/Resource/views/, but this views are not inside MyBundle/Resource/views/Product.
So views are not divided in directories and also the CRUD command doesn't create it

Comment: another thing: with this line

$dir = sprintf('%s/Resources/views/%s', $this->rootDir, str_replace('\\', '/', strtolower($this->entity)));

Doctrine create the dir correctly, but in the wrong place. This situation is a "bug"? I don't think that anyone must to change the crud.class to do this... also because was different in the 2.x symfony version...

Comment: THIS WORK FINE!

$dir = sprintf('%s/Resources/views/%s', $this->bundle->getPath(), str_replace('\\', '/', strtolower($this->entity)));

Comment: ps: i think that the dir was changed, in the 3rd version, because if you have different bundles you must to navigate through different directories to change views.... maybe... so putting all views inside the root it's "easier" to change UI at a glance

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood what your are trying to do, glad to help any way.

Answer (score 0):

```
symfony/app/CustomBundle/resources/views/test
```

you should find it there , and it depends on which version you are using ps your tagging symfony 3 and symfony2 so !!!

Comment: as i wrote in my question i don't find the view inside my customBundle. i find it in the view directory of symfony, under symfony/app/resource/views/test (PS: the views works fine and i'm using symfony 3)

Comment: i'm using Symfony 3.0.4-DEV

Comment: okey so when you run the sever did it work  ? what does it say

Comment: maybe i must to declare something in config.yml ?

Comment: Well of course you should change it to you database settings ps .yml is pretty sensitive so when you try to chage anything don't add special chars or even space it won't run but i dont get your problem if the crud is generated with no problem then it should work even the path isn't the same else maybe because you didn t put your database that why its not reacting like it should be i can't tell because you didnt mention you error in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your need to change :

`yoursymfonydir/vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Generator/DoctrineCrudGenerator.php:`

```
   public function generate(.....) {
   .....
   /*comment this line*/
     //$dir = sprintf('%s/Resources/views/%s', $this->rootDir, strtolower($entity));
   /*replace by*/
     //Create the views inside the bundle :
     $dir = sprintf('%s/Resources/views/%s', $this->bundle->getPath(), $entity);
   .....
   }
```

and in the `yoursymfonydir/vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Resources/skeleton/crud/actions/edit.php.twig, index.php.twig, new.php.twig, show.php.twig`, you need to change the line with render( in each files in this way :

```
return $this->render('{{ entity|lower|replace({'\\': '/'}) }}/edit.html.twig', array(
```

replaced by

```
return $this->render('{{ bundle }}:{{ entity }}:edit.html.twig', array(
```